# Grails ID in the URL

Tags: spring, groovy, grails, spring-security

I'm developing an application using `Grails 6.1.0` and `Grails Spring security core 6.1.0 plugin` found [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/6.0.x/index.html) and followed what was mentioned in this [tutorial](https://grails.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/6.0.x/index.html#tutorials) while working I noticed that the user can access other users data by only changing the id in the URL, for example, `http://localhost/appName/profile/show/1` if I change the **id** param to `2` rather `1` I can access other user's data and so on for any controller and action, I'm using the default GSPs for `login, forgotPassword` that come with `Spring security UI`, users are authenticated via entering credentials (username and password were saved in the DB), here are the `Security configs` found in `application.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.security.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.security.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.invalidateHttpSession = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.filterProcessesUrl= '/logoff' 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.defaultRoleNames = ['ROLE_USER']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.postRegisterUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.postResetUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.postLogoutUrl ='/login/auth'   
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl='/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl="/"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.defaultRoleNames = ['ROLE_USER']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.postRegisterUrl = '/'
```

I thought about using `filters` to check whether the logged-in user is the owner of the profile or not, but still wondering if is there any proper and secured way to prevent this?

Comment: Shouldn't profile only be for admins, and a separate URL added for the currently logged in user to edit their own information?